# ASP.Net Core 2 RedirectToPage does not redirect when used with DropzoneJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, dropzone.js, razor-pages

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2 Razorpages with dropzonejs to have a dragndrop fileupload on my index site after the user drops a file I want to redirect to my LoadingPage.

However I'm having problems with the page being redirected. Strangely the OnGet() method of the page I want to redirect to is being called, but the site in the browser never gets updated. Other redirects work just fine, so I suspect the issue to be something with dropzonejs.

Well, here is my code:

**index.cshtml**

```
<div id="fileuploadcontainer">
            <form method="post"
                  class="dropzone"
                  id="music-dropzone"
                  asp-page="./Index">
            </form>
            <br />
</div>
```

**index.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [...]//this here is my file uploading, but the problem still persits even when removed

        return RedirectToPage("/LoadingPage/Loading");
    }
```

**Loading.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        [...]//this part here gets called just fine, but the site doesnt redirect, even when it is minfied to only return Page() :(
        return Page();
    }
```

I also already tried to remove the async modifiers, but to no avail...

**Edit - Workaround:**
I have tried any possible combination and solution I can think of but my problem still persists. However I found a nice workaround, you can use the events of dropzonejs and then redirect the page using JS. The code for that would be:

```
<script>
    Dropzone.options.[yourDropzoneElementId] = {
        maxFilesize: 10, // Mb
        init: function () {
            // Set up any event handlers
            this.on('success', function () {

                window.location.replace("/LoadingPage/Loading");
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: The method signatures have async. Can you confirm that are in fact using async/await in the body of those actions.

Comment: Hey @Nkosi, thanks for your response. Both methods have an await statement in them. 

The OnPost in index waits for the file to finish uploading and the Loading OnGet starts some analyzing of the file which it awaits. But I also already removed the async/await components of the Loading OnGet and it still didnt work.

Comment: and the `OnGet` returns Page?

Comment: When posting questions you need to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. It will also save on unnecessary back and forth questions as those trying to help will have a clear understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thats correct. I have my OnGet in Loading very minified right now. it only is

`public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }`